# Reading CSV with multiLine option and encoding option

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

In azure Databricks when i am reading a CSV file with `multiline = 'true'` and `encoding = 'SJIS'` it seems like encoding option is being ignored.
If i use `multiline` option spark use its default `encoding` that is `UTF-8`,
but my file is in `SJIS` format.
Is there any solution for it, any help appreciate.
Here is my code that I am  using, and I am using pyspark.

```
df= sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='false',delimiter='\t',encoding='SJIS',multiline='true').load('/mnt/Data/Data.tsv')
```

Comment: Please try to update ```encoding``` with ```charset```.  For more details, please refer to https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv. For example, use the following code ```df = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true', charset='sjis').load('/mnt/csvdir/Book1.csv')```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jim Xu . i tried with `charset` but result is same, maybe you are missing my point, problem is when i use `multiline`  `charset` or `encoding` is being ignored and return to default setup that is `UTF-8`,

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, when we read csv file in Azure datatricks, it does not support options multiline. So I suggest you update your code as below.

```
df= spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true',inferSchema='false',delimiter='\t',charset='SJIS').load('/FileStore/tables/test.csv')
```

[image]
For more details, please refer to https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html. 
[image]

Comment: You said "when we read csv file in Azure datatricks, it does not support options multiline"
I don't think so, it support `multiline` option but when you use `multiline` option it is gonna ignore your `charset` option.
That is my problem, so try to understand my problem please. 

Is there any way to use both(multiline, charset) together?

Comment: @SohelReza According to my research, we cannot use "multiline" and "charset" together. For more details, please refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/615746fd-2c3a-4f1c-bcbe-438822e406c8/how-to-read-csv-file-with-other-encoding-in-azure-databricks?forum=AzureDataFactory

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use "multiline" and "charset" together, if you use together encoding will be set to default.

Azure Databricks charset: defaults to UTF-8 but can be set to other valid charset names.

To explain this clearly, I have taken an example of the encoding SJIS signature “**Cash+邃｢ Signatureﾂｮ**” taken as column "**signature**" on the input file.

This is expected behaviour, if you use `multiline=true` and `encoding/charset to “SJIS”`, which returns the output same as `default charset UTF-8`.

[image]

**Default:** Charset "UTF-8"

[image]

**Encoding/charset to "SJIS"**:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,
Unfortunately, you cannot use "multiline" and "charset" together, if you use together encoding will be set to default.
For more details, refer “Spark – Known issue": http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201804.mbox/%3C4787e1a70cda4381927debecd20b606d@git.apache.org%3E

Comment: Thanks for your response , so is there any alternative solution or i just have to change my source file?