# PySpark is not able to read multiline with utf-8 encoding

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

While using PySpark options multiline + utf-8 (charset), we are not able to read data in its correct format.

After digging got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262846/reading-csv-with-multiline-option-and-encoding-option) which is on similar lines but for databricks. This works fine with Scala spark, but not able to read in PySpark.

Is anything missing or need to be implemented in a different way?

Comment: Could you post some sample data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Nikunj, its not possible to get sample data, same data i had tested on diff system it works fine, but unfortunately its not working on client machine, with python 3.6 and spark 2.4.5., as a workaround we used panda dataframe and then converted to spark data frame that resolved issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

Please try read it as text file:

```
spark.read.text()
```

with your charset.

Than do rest of steps as explained here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-multiline-multiple-line-csv-file/

- Replace all delimiters with escape character + delimiter + escape character “,”. - If you have comma separated file then it would replace, with “,”.
- Add escape character to the end of each record (write logic to ignore this for rows that have multiline).
- Write data into another temporary file.
- Finally, read this file as CSV with multiline and escape options.